# simple question on Getters/Setters (accessors and mutators) in android

Tags: java, android, getter-setter

Been stuck on this for two days embarrassingly. Getters and setters not working. Just causing a fatal exception.

Please see code below.

SearchNumber.java is the getter/setter method.

All the app does is send the edittext(number) to the setter when you press the sendToSetter button.

This is the error code on run: here is the error:

```
V/Toast: Toast SHOW: android.widget.Toast@13d7808 view = null pkg: com.example.gettersettertest TextToast? true caller: com.example.gettersettertest.MainActivity$1.onClick:34 android.view.View.performClick:7503 com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick:1202 android.view.View.performClickInternal:7480 android.view.View.access$3600:813 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.gettersettertest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

Button BTN_sendToSetter, BTN_getFromGetter;
EditText EditNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BTN_sendToSetter = findViewById(R.id.BTN_sendToSetter);
        BTN_getFromGetter = findViewById(R.id.BTN_getFromGetter);
        EditNumber = findViewById(R.id.EditNumber);


            BTN_sendToSetter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SetButtonworking:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    String thesearchnumber = EditNumber.getText().toString();
                    Log.i(thesearchnumber, "thesearchnumber");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "searchnumber:" + thesearchnumber , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //everything working so far. Try  getter and setter
                    SearchNumber obj = new SearchNumber();

                    obj.setSearchNumber(thesearchnumber);
                    String objRet = obj.getSearchNumber();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "searchnumberOBJ" + objRet , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



        });

            BTN_getFromGetter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GetButtonWorking:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
}
```

SearchNumber.java

```
package com.example.gettersettertest;


import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;

public class SearchNumber{
    private String mSearchNumber;


    //no constructor


    // getter and setter
    public String getSearchNumber() { //The get method returns the value of the variable.
        Log.i("GET SearchNumber  is " , mSearchNumber);
        return mSearchNumber;

    }

    public void setSearchNumber(String sentSearchNumber) { //The set method takes a parameter  and assigns it to the name variable. The this keyword is used to refer to the current object.
        Log.i("setSearchNumber  is " , mSearchNumber);
        this.mSearchNumber = sentSearchNumber; //this instance refers to the current instance itself
        Log.i("setSearchNumber  is " , mSearchNumber);
    }
// getter and setter end
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTN_getFromGetter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="getFromGetter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTN_sendToSetter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="sendToSetter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/BTN_getFromGetter"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="244dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:hint="hinthere"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/BTN_getFromGetter"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="174dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:hint="ID: editNumber"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="174dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

just expecting the parameters sent in EditNumber to be sent to the getter/setter method. Thats all.

Comment: just curious to know why do you need a Getter/Setter over here if you need to just send a  particular value. What is your exact requirement please? Also please post the exact exception as seen in the Logcat window in Android Studio

Comment: its part of a bigger program. here is the error: V/Toast: Toast SHOW: android.widget.Toast@13d7808 view = null pkg: com.example.gettersettertest TextToast? true caller: com.example.gettersettertest.MainActivity$1.onClick:34 android.view.View.performClick:7503 com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick:1202 android.view.View.performClickInternal:7480 android.view.View.access$3600:813 
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: @TimWNewark you should [edit] the post instead of posting exception in the comments